# The difference between storage/framework/views and resources/views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have s little problem with understand what's the difference between the files laravel_core/storage/framework/views and laravel_core/resources/views.
In both directories there are blades vies, but there are not equal and the names at storage views are random.

This are pictures for files examples:

Image:1
[image: Image 1]

Image:2
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `resources/views`

In `resources/views` are the views you create and modify. See the [Laravel 8 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-views):

> Views contain the HTML served by your application and separate your controller / application logic from your presentation logic. Views are stored in the `resources/views` directory.

2. `storage/framework/views`

As the [documentation explains](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#optimizing-views):

> By default, views are compiled on demand.

Unless a compiled view that's up-to-date already exists. These are cached and stored in `storage/framework/views` and that's why they look so unintelligible. See also this [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/998933):

> The view cache is always stored via the filesystem in `storage/framework/views`.

Btw., if you want to precompile them, you can use the command

- `php artisan view:cache`

and to clear them

- `php artisan view:clear`

Apart from these two commands you are unlikely to have to do anything with the compiled views. You work with the "normal" views, create them, write code etc.